# Configure Firewall to allow OSC communication

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall

I've installed an OSC app on my smartphone (TouchOSC) to control a music software on my laptop (SuperCollider). For it to work, I have to disable the laptop's Firewall. My laptop is running Windows 7.

I would like to adapt the firewall configuration to enable the OSC communication without having to disable the firewall. But I don't where to start. Any advise ?

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to lookup the ports that your app needs, or you need to use wireshark to monitor network traffic and find out the ports that way.

You will still have a potential attack vector, but at least it will be as small as possible.
[image]

I clicked the start menu and typed "firewall" and the windows firewall appears.

Here you can see I have click on "new rule" in the windows firewall.